fastest way to repeat a list
I need do some speed test on my Linux commands. The input data is a list of words. For example:
$ cat list
elephant
horse
raven
cat
dog
fish

For a reasonable speed test I need to have a much larger file. What is the fastest way to repeat the above list hundreds of thousands of times?

What have you tried? A simple Google search provides plenty of results on methods that will do this.

$ jot -b "elephant
> horse
> raven
> cat
> dog
> fish" 100000 > list

jot is a tool that is usually found by default on BSD systems (including macOS) but can also be installed on most Linux systems. The package on Ubuntu, for example, is called athena-jot.

Very interesting use of jot, thanks for this; Is there a way to use a file (list in this case) instead of typing the list?

echo "A" > /tmp/foo; jot -b "$(cat /tmp/foo)" 10 works for me on ksh, but it might depend on your shell

Never knew about jot. Looks very compact and easy to use. Will install it on my Ubuntu to check it out. Thanks

Here's one way, using perl:
perl -ge 'print <> x 10' < list 

The -g flag tells perl to read the entire file at once and to execute the script given by -e on it. The script itself just uses the special perl syntax <> which represents standard input and then we print @list times 10. On your input, with x 3 for simplicity, that gives:
$ perl -ge 'print <> x 3' < list 
elephant
horse
raven
cat
dog
fish
elephant
horse
raven
cat
dog
fish
elephant
horse
raven
cat
dog
fish

So if you want thousands, just do something like
perl -ge 'print <> x 100000000' < list > big.list

On my system, that creates a file of 3.2G in under 5 seconds:
$ time perl -ge 'print <> x 100000000' < list > big.list

real    0m4.705s
user    0m0.509s
sys 0m1.769s

$ ls -lh big.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 3.2G May  3 13:25 big.list


Strictly speaking, <> does not represent standard input. STDIN  is the standard input filehandle, <STDIN> would read one record from it in scalar contexts and all records in list contexts, but <> is very special, it does (eventually) read from the ARGV handle. When @ARGV is empty, it reads from stdin. See perldoc perlop for details.

@StéphaneChazelas yes, but in this context, it is stdin so I figured it's easier to explain that way. Perl's special stuff like $_ and <> have so many different applications i different contexts, it is very easy to get confused.

When I run that perl command as time perl -ge 'print <> x 100000000' < list > big.list I get timing results of around 7 seconds.  When I just change the output file name to /dev/null I get timing results of around 2 seconds. Do you see a similar difference and, if so, do you have any idea why it's much longer writing to a real file vs writing to /dev/null? I don't see a noticeable timing difference between output to a real file and /dev/null using awk.

@EdMorton I get more or less the same speedup using > /dev/shm/somefile as I do with > /dev/null so I am assuming it's SSD vs RAM speed or just writing vs discarding (I don't know the details of how /dev/null is implemented in Linux). I know I've seen this (/dev/null speeding things up) before and I'm quite surprised you don't see it with awk. My first guess is that you're looping in awk so the speedup isn't noticeable, but if you're doing one of your clever awk tricks, then I don't know. Could be worth posting a question!

I'm just looping, printing N times as trying to append to a variable N times then printing once would be very slow. I may ask a question, thanks for the suggestion.

With some head implementations:
yes -- "$(cat list)" | head -c1G

Would give you 1GiB worth of the contents of list repeated indefinitely.
With ksh/zsh/bash, you can replace "$(cat list)" with "$(<list)".
-c is not a standard option of head, and not all implementations that support it, support those KMGTPE... suffixes. Also note that it will likely cut a line in its middle and leave it undelimited.
yes -- "$(cat list)" | head -n 1000000

To print 1000000 lines worth would be standard and portable.

Double up repeatedly. This code is efficient in that it loops only log2 n times for an increase in file size by a factor of n. (1 iteration for twice the size, 2 iterations for four times the size, etc.)
for f in {1..17}; do cat list list > addition && mv -f addition list; done

This will give you a multiplication factor of 131072 (217), which matches your requirement to "repeat the above list hundreds of thousands of times".
You could use cat a a a a to raise by 49 instead, achieving a multiplication factor of 262144 with 9 iterations.
for f in {1..9}; do cat list list list list > addition && mv -f addition list; done

The {1..17} construct is a brace expansion supported by less minimalist shells such as ksh, bash, zsh (but not dash or POSIX)

Just use a for loop:
#!/bin/bash

limit=100
file="list.txt"
content="$(< "$file")"

for ((i = 0; i < limit; i++)); do
    printf '%s\n' "$content"
done >> "$file"

This basically appends the initial content of the given list n times to the same file. Adjust limit and file to make it work the way you want.
If the actual content of the list is not important, you could do something more flexible and just append an arbitrary string to a file, like so:
for ((i = 0; i < limit; i++)); do
    printf '%s\n' $RANDOM
done > newlist.txt

Or directly from the command line using a more concise syntax:
$ for _ in {1..100}; do printf '%s\n' $RANDOM; done > newlist.txt

Edit: Thanks to @muru for the suggestion. Of course, doing a redirect on each iteration is not efficient, appending the generated content right after the for loop is much better and faster. I've updated the answer accordingly.
Update
If efficiency is a concern and a more scalable solution is required, you can make use of the external commands seq and shuf to generate a random list of the size you need:
$ seq 1 100 | shuf > newlist.txt

To see the difference more clearly, let's increase the number of iterations to 1,000,000 and measure the time:
$ limit=1000000
$ time seq 1 $limit | shuf > newlist.txt
real    0m0.157s
user    0m0.136s
sys     0m0.034s

This is almost 40 times faster than running the for loop with $RANDOM, which took 5.935s on my machine with the same limit.

As you do not care about the repeat numbers, you can combine "timeout" and "yes" commands to create huge repeats very quickly. For example:
$ timeout 0.01s yes "$(<list)" >>very_long.txt

Change the time argument of 0.01 seconds to suit your needs. Keep it low as even with 1s you could end up with 50 million lines!

You could pipe the output though e.g. "head -n 10000000" (or whatever number) to get a specific number of lines. Or you could use "dd bs=1 count=100000" (or whatever) to control the number of bytes written if you'd rather want that.
